# what is this ext.js's "xtype: 'app-main'"

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

Newbie to ext.js: I am trying to understand what is this:

```
xtype: 'app-main'
```

means in my auto generated code. No documentation available. I guess this is a reference to so me alias, but I could not find it..

I used sencha cmd (latest may 2014 - ext.js 4.2.2) which autogenerated a number of files, which had **xtype: 'app-main'** in them...

**Main.js**

```
Ext.define('test12.view.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
    requires:[
        'Ext.tab.Panel',
        'Ext.layout.container.Border'
    ],

    xtype: 'app-main',    <<<<-------

    layout: {
        type: 'border'
    },

    items: [{
        region: 'west',
        xtype: 'panel',
        title: 'west',
        width: 150
    },{
        region: 'center',
        xtype: 'tabpanel',
        items:[{
            title: 'Center Tab 1'
        }]
    }]
});
```

**viewport.js**

```
Ext.define('test12.view.Viewport', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',
    requires:[
        'Ext.layout.container.Fit',
        'test12.view.Main'
    ],

    layout: {
        type: 'fit'
    },

    items: [{
        xtype: 'app-main'
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**xtype is a config that allow you to instantiate the classes you define more easily**

Example:

```
Ext.define('Myapp.view.MyCoolPanel',{
    extend : 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    xtype  : 'coolpanel',
    //some cool configs ... 

});
//somewhere else 
Ext.create('Ext.window.Window',{
    //regular configs

    items: [
    {
      xtype: 'coolpanel'

    }
]
}).show();
```

see http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel-cfg-xtype

best regards

Comment: Ok, I got that part, but what about the 'app-main' ?

Comment: are you using architect or why do you call it auto generated?

Answer (score 0):

So, it seems that xtype: ... inside a Ext.defing( ... ) {
sets the new view to the xtype, in this case app-main.

Makes sense ;)